Builds failing with unknown: Props Authentication Token not found error
We've a Jenkins build that pulls image from dockerhub internal registry and spins a container and does build operations inside. Every 1 out of 2 builds fail with below error.
17:24:47  Step 1/25 : FROM dockerhub.internalregistry.com/walle-build-docker/tdd/tdd_base:51
17:24:47  Head "https://dockerhub.internalregistry.com/v2/walle-build-docker/tdd/tdd_base/manifests/51": unknown: Props Authentication Token not found
17:24:53  Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB

We use a generic user and its token which has access to read and write to this specific repository in our internal registry. The hosts where it runs is all uniform. Sometimes it even fails on the same host where it succeeded once. What could be the cause for such failures?
